# How to debug on Sony Ericsson X10i

Tags: android, x10

when i try to debug on X10 but on screen select device i haven't see X10 device (Only have AVD device).

I was intall driver: Sony_Ericsson_PC_Companion_2.00.146_Web.exe but nothing happen.
Anyone have experiment with this device please give me suggest.
Thanks for your help

@Update solution:
I got solution: just flow steps:

```
Menu -> Settings -> Applications -> Development -> USB Debugging!
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect what you've downloaded isn't the USB drivers.

The drivers are here: http://developer.sonyericsson.com/wportal/devworld/downloads/download/dw-x10drivers?cc=gb&lc=en

I haven't installed these, but my boss did recently. He told me that he had to hand edit the config file to get it working (changed the product id from D12E to 212E). Don't know if this is an oddity of the phone in New Zealand or not, but if you find you still have issues once you've got the driver, this could be why.

`abd devices` from the command line will tell you if you've got the phone connected correctly.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks SamStephens: Menu -> Settings -> Applications -> Development -> USB Debugging!

Answer (score 2):

Okay,

I've had the same issue. This is how I solved it:

- From the device-manager, I got the hardware-id of the device that failed to install (under details, you can get the hardware-id, in my case these Hardware-Id's were listed:
  USB\VID_0FCE&PID_612E&REV_0224&MI_01
  USB\VID_0FCE&PID_612E&MI_01

I then opened the inf-file (sa0101usb.inf), and under the sections: [SEMC.NTx86] and [SEMC.NTamd64] I added a new entry with the new key...

I.e.:

> %CompositeAdbInterface%     = USB_Install, USB\VID_0FCE&PID_612E&MI_01

Then installing the drivers worked like a charm...

Regards